# Check for a Link in Javascript/PHP Widget

Tags: php, javascript, security, widget, copy-protection

I created my own Javascript/PHP widget that takes info from my site, and allows other users to put it on their own. I'd like to know how I can put in some "Link Protection". The reason I made the widget is so that I can gain some valuable links from those who decide to use my widget on their site. The site I got the tutorial from is

http://php-drops.blogspot.ca/2011/04/creating-widget-with-javascript-and-php.html

When I look at the source code, the link to the site is not visible since it is being brought up in an iframe. What I wanted to do is to put a separate `<div>` that will have something like

```
<div id="my_copyright">Data provided by <a href="http://www.example.com">Example.com</a></div>
```

How would I go about protecting the data so that if the user tries to remove the link, alter the `<a>` tag to a `rel="nofollow"` or any other "work arounds", the data will not load and post an alert() and not load the data?

Any help would be great! The script currently uses 1 JS file 1 PHP file that extracts data from MySQL and prints out the data needed.

Comment: You can't do it reliably. Someone could just remove the code that checks whether it's been modified.

Comment: So is there absolutely nothing I can do to protect my code? Or possibly to track and block who's altering the code?

Comment: If you distribute it as source code, and it doesn't need anything from your server, they can just take out the tracking code. You could minify it so it's hard for them to find the code to modify.

Answer (score 0):

As Barmar suggested, your only option is security through obscurity. The success of this depends on your audience. For a casual webmaster, it might deter him from chaning your code. It just increases the "can't be arsed" factor.

1) Minify your code : http://fmarcia.info/jsmin/test.html

2) Use a JS packer/obfuscator : http://dean.edwards.name/packer/

Comment: I'm actually more curious on how I can put in the HTML link and have it so that if they try to remove or alter the link, then they'll get an error. For example, if they're given something like this to copy and paste into their site, then if they try to remove the <a href="myurl.com">My Anchor Text</a> then it won't parse. This is my JS code they can copy and paste.

<div id="wd_id"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/script.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">init_widget(300,300,"all","current","TITLE")</script>
<a href="www.example.com">MyAnchor</a>